# PHP array index from SQL field

Tags: php, sql, arrays, indexing

Apologies is advance as I am very much a PHP amateur...

I currently have the following code that extracts all of the values from an SQL table field.

```
$unit_data = mysql_query("SELECT `value1` FROM `unit_stats`");
$unit_info = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($unit_data)) {
    $unit_info[] = $row['value1'];
}
print_r($unit_info);
```

The array uses standard indexing ([0], [1] etc) so my output is:

```
Array ( [0] => 40 [1] => 30 [2] => 70 ...)
```

However I need to use another field within the same SQL table as my Index rather than the standard numerical method.  E.g.

```
Array ( [item1] => 40 [item2] => 30 [item3] => 70 ... )
```

Can anyone advise a solution?

Regards,
Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are selecting the other field in your select statement, you could simply define the key as below.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($unit_data)) {
    $unit_info[$row['index_value_from_sql']] = $row['value1'];
}
```

Arrays in php can be used as maps that associates one value (index) to the other (value). Index does not need to be the default numeric values. You can define them according to your liking. Hope this helps.

Comment: That's the ticket!  I tried something similar earlier but I can see where I went wrong.  Many thanks!